# Support vector regression from sklearn gives flat prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a support vector regression on this [data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires) and I think I am initiating the SVR is wrong possibly with the way that I am calling the variables or using the kernel. The code for the MWE is quite long so I've commented it heavily and highlighted the relevant portion

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import scikit_posthocs as sp
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVR

#read in data https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires
df = pd.read_csv('forestfires.csv')

df['transformed_area']=np.log10(df['area']+1)        #transform area- the target varaible
df_ohe=pd.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True)            # one hot encode catagorical variables
labels = np.array(df_ohe['transformed_area'])        # seperate labels from what is being labeled
df_ohe =df_ohe.drop(['transformed_area','area'],axis=1)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(df_ohe,labels,test_size = 0.30, random_state = 42)

#I think it goes wrong after this point 

# Scale training and testing sets
scaler            = MinMaxScaler((-1,1))
scaler.fit(df_ohe)

rescaled_X_train =scaler.transform(X_train)
rescaled_X_test  =scaler.transform(X_test)

#put back in feature names
rescaled_X_train = pd.DataFrame(rescaled_X_train,columns=list(X_train))
rescaled_X_test  = pd.DataFrame(rescaled_X_test,columns=list(X_train))

# Instantiate model 
svr = SVR()
# Train the model on training data
svr.fit(rescaled_X_train, Y_train)
```

When I plot the predicted values vs actual values for the transformed_area I get these graphs, i.e. the predicted value is constant for all X data.

I am using the way of instantiating the model/ training the model that I am used to for sklearn models and recalling the data. Do SVRs require anything else?

[image]

Comment: Hope it is clearer now (after the answer) why, instead of verbal descriptions like "*I plot the predicted values vs actual values*", we ask for the *exact code* used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like perhaps you are predicting on the unscaled inputs, when you should be predicting with the scaled inputs (that's what your model was trained on).  (Next time, include the prediction plotting code, since that would've made it easier to spot.)

When I run your code and generate predictions (`svr.predict(rescaled_X_train)` or `svr.predict(rescaled_X_test)`), I get a range of values between -0.07 and 1.33, which doesn't look like your plots.  When I try to predict *without* scaling (`svr.predict(X_train)` or `svr.predict(X_test)`), then I do get essentially constant predictions near 0.5.